# Как работает плагин img-min для Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Подскажите, как работает плагин **img-min** для **Gulp**'а, должен ли он уменьшать размер изображения или нет ? 
Вот код файла **gulpfile.js**:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('full/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
    // Caching images that ran through imagemin
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        interlaced: true,
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('done/img'))
  });
```

Если что-то не так настроено, просьба показать более эффективный код.

**Дополнение:**

Я так понимаю, что этот плагин должен уменьшать размер изображения, но он абсолютно ничего не уменьшает. В чем проблема?

Comment: И что конкретно у вас не работает? В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что этот плагин должен уменьшать размер изображения, но он абсолютно ничего не уменьшает. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Есть шанс, что изображения просто уже некуда сжимать. Вы можете побитово сравнить исходные и целевые изображения? Есть различия?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать ? Если это в свойствах нужно смотреть глубину цвета, то она не изменилась (24). 
Сжимать есть куда, потому как TinyPng сжимает эту картинку до 400кБ.